# Is there a module to convert a tensorflow NN to Jax?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jax

There is a [libary to convert Jax functions to Tensorflow functions](https://github.com/google/jax/tree/main/jax/experimental/jax2tf). Is there a similar library to convert TensorFlow functions to Jax functions?

Comment: this suggestion isn't possible at the moment, but one could imagine using onnx as an intermediate format. `jax --> onnx --> tf`. but `jax --> onnx` doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: @jakub Yep, I had a look at that but couldnt find anything

Comment: you can check https://github.com/deepmind/tf2jax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no library supported by the JAX team to convert tensorflow into JAX in a manner similar to how `jax.experimental.jax2tf` converts JAX code to tensorflow, and I have not seen any such library developed by others.

Comment: Do you think there are any hacky ways to allow a tensorflow NN to be used in Jax? I dont need to modify or train the neural network any more, I only need to use it. For instance, could I do something to create a XLA HLO graph and then load it into Jax, within python? I saw this discussion - https://github.com/google/jax/issues/45 - But it is closed now

Comment: You might have more luck generating some ideas if you ask at https://github.com/google/jax/discussions

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/jax/experimental/jax2tf/README.md.

"jax2tf.call_tf: for using TensorFlow functions in a JAX context, e.g., to call a TensorFlow library or a SavedModel inside a JAX function."

That is what you need. So you can call tf function under jax context.

for example:

```
# Compute cos with TF and sin with JAX
def cos_tf_sin_jax(x):
  return jax.numpy.sin(jax2tf.call_tf(cos_tf)(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Is https://github.com/google-deepmind/tf2jax what you were looking for? It only works for TF v2 though.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no library similar to the one you mentioned to convert TensorFlow functions to Jax functions. I'm sorry